# Highlight all spaces except at start and at end of paragraph regex approach

Tags: regex, vba

I have the following link
https://regex101.com/r/8XGVeZ/1

The pattern used is `\b +\b` to select all the spaces except at the start and the end of the paragrph
Have a look at the picture to know what I mean

[image]

I need to include those spaces inside the paragraph as shown in orange squares

I tried the following pattern (but not exact true)

```
\b(?!^)\s+(?!$)\b
```

The problem of this pattern is that it matches all spaces and in between \n and I need to deal with each spaces separately

Comment: with lookarounds: `(?<=[\w\n]) +(?=[\w\n])`

Comment: Thanks a lot. This seems to do the task. I will try on my original text and back to you if I have any other notes.

Comment: Can you have a look at this link https://regex101.com/r/OgYFus/1?fbclid=IwAR0j0ZzJjXqZeQbb_VNVqLnmXCeccXRrxp1YXP8reSg3zfajm6VQY6JgQU8?

Comment: I think this is OK `(?<=[\n\S]) +(?=[\n\S])`

Comment: It will still fail([shown here](https://regex101.com/r/rtpuEw/1)) to not match the white-spaces before and after the para.

Comment: You have not specified any language or the regex engine you are using. If you are working on .NET, you can use the regex - [`(?<!\A\s*)(?>\s+)(?!\z)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5cA%5cs*%29%28%3f%3e%5cs%2b%29%28%3f!%5cz%29&i=++%0d%0a%0d%0a++%0d%0a%0d%0a%0d%0a+++++%0d%0a%0d%0a%0d%0a+++++a++b++cc+++-++-+++ff++%0d%0a++ff++s++gg++++++++++_++++++-++++ss++%0d%0a%0d%0a%0d%0a++%0d%0a++%0d%0a). If you are using PCRE, this is the closest I could reach [`\A\s+\K|\s++(?!\z)`](https://regex101.com/r/gdxJUQ/1).

Comment: Sorry I am using VBA.

Comment: In VBA regex, you can't use lookbehinds. So, what are you going to do with the spaces you match? Replace? What with? Please provide a *full* test case. A short relevant code snippet would help.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:
`/(?<=[\w\n\-])\s+(?=[\w\n\-])/g`

[image: Example Match on RegExr]

Be aware that positive lookbehind is not supported on all browsers according to [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/?search=lookbehind).

I would also recommend sticking to "\s" insead of " " because \s matches all space-characters.

If as comments pointed out lookbehind is not supported you might want:
`/[\w\n\-](\s+)[\w\n\-]/g`
Then you can reference the Space by `$1` or `\1`.

If you want to remove them you could:
`/([\w\n\-])(\s+)([\w\n\-])/g`
and replace with something like `\1\3`.

Comment: Thanks but this didn't work for me.

Comment: After the modification, the results include letters within the results and the spaces are the only needed

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you have a look https://regex101.com/r/OgYFus/1?fbclid=IwAR0j0ZzJjXqZeQbb_VNVqLnmXCeccXRrxp1YXP8reSg3zfajm6VQY6JgQU8?

Comment: If you mean by the link that you also want to match spaces after the "-", I have updated the answer to comply.

Comment: This won't work in VBA where the regex cannot contain lookbehinds. Also, what is `b` flag doing here?

Comment: The b flag was a typo and I actually wrote to be cautious whether the lookbehind is supported. And VBA was not a concern in the question.